# Getting the correct keys and values to display from JSON file in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Trying to retrieve specific values in complicated nested JSON arrays is proving tricky. I'm thinking theres another way to do this than what i have below:

```
 $.getJSON('test.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.glossary, function (){
     $('ul#results').append('<li><div class=\"name\">' +this.title+ '</div></li><li><div class=\"name\">' +this.GlossTerm+ '</div></li>');
    });
});
```

Where test.json is:

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "Hello!!",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So far on the web page, the returned results are:

+undefined

+undefined

+Hello!!

+undefined

How would I make the undefined values display the correct value? I've tried numerous methods and none seem to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to traverse the object properly, no way around that ?

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.glossary, function(index, val){
       var title = val.title, //"example glossary"
           term  = val.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossTerm; //"Standard Generalized Markup Language"
    });
});
```